# Get Lang from database Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I try to make multi language site in codeigniter, but i have a problem....

I want two lang (englush, german). and switch without url.... in admin panel settings i have:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="language">Language</label>
    <select name="language" class="form-control">
       <option value="english">English</option>
       <option value="german" selected="selected">Deutsch</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

In db have settings table and write only selected lang.
 settings table:
 id 1| language german

I have a model who get value

```
    function getLang(){
    $this->db->select('language');
    $this->db->where('id',1);
    $data=$this->db->get('settings')->result_array();
    return $data[0];
}
```

And Core-> My_Controller:

```
 $this->load->model('Setting');
    $this->lang->load('admin', $this->Setting->getLang()); //admin_lang.php is located in language folder in english and german folders
```

When i change the value in database language do not change... load only default language from config.php `$config['language']   = 'english';`

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

*Your model's method `getLang` should be like this, do this to return language*

```
function getLang()
{
    $this->db->select('language');
    $this->db->where('id',1);
    $query =$this->db->get('settings');
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        return $query->row()->language;
    }
}
```